# jquery tabbed ui - javascript in loaded code not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQuery tabbed widget as a menu for my application and have managed to set up the tabbed interface so that when you click a tab it shows the first page of that section.  According to the docs, if you click on a link on this page and want it to load in the same tab then you need to use the code below.  This partially works because now when I click on an image-hyperlink on that page it renders the new page in the tabbed window.

**However, when I click on a button which has javascript the button no longer works.  This is the case for all of the javascript.  How can I get the javascript working again under the new tabbed interface?**

```
$('#example').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT:  So if you add the following line to LeftyX's code in the page 1 file, then the button causes page4.html to open but does not do it in the tab

```
<button onclick="location.href='Page4.html'">Test button </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must work.
If you show us your HTML we might try to help.
You can check my [sample](http://leftyx.somee.com/jQueryUI_Tabs/index.html) and [download](http://leftyx.somee.com/jQueryUI_Tabs/jQueryUI_Tabs.zip) the code.

Try and check if there are any errors in your script using some Dev Tools (ex: Google Chrome Developer Tools)

UPDATE:

if you're using a button you can use some HTML5 attribute:

```
<button data-pagelink="Page4.html">Test button</button>
```

and trap the click event:

```
$(ui.panel).delegate('button', 'click', function(event, o) {
    $(ui.panel).load(this.dataset.pagelink);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or use an hyperlink and transform it in a button:

```
<a id="thisIsAButton" href="Page4.html">go to page 4</a>
```

with this:

```
$("#thisIsAButton").button();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply LeftyX - in your code you are using hyperlinks, but in my code I have buttons which have onclick attributes to direct to another php file.  The onclick has stopped working now.  I will try to get some code up - thanks for help!

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the help! Something odd is happening!  I tried your method and it works for some buttons.  However, for some of the buttons which trigger jQuery at first it doesn't work but if you keep clicking the buttons it eventually works!  Any idea why?

Comment: hi!  I've actually asked the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202780/jquery-tabbed-ui-buttons-only-start-working-after-switching-tab - it has a "simplified" version of my code there - any pointers would be appreciated!  Thanks :D

Comment: @user1058210: It seems that you're missing some scripts there. Have a look at my sample code here and see how you should load your jQuery/jQuery UI scripts.

Comment: I've copied your header files and it's still not working.  Do you think this could have anything to do with the fact I'm using PHP files not html?  It's the main difference I can see between out code

Comment: @user1058210: PHP renders HTML. You should check for errors in your HTML using a debugger.