# jQuery tabbed UI using AJAX - event handlers for buttons no longer working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery tabbed interface to switch between views of my Facebook application using ajax.  I have two tabs - tab1 and tab2 which both have buttons on them of the form .

The problem is that when I go to tab1 and click the buttons they do not work.  If I then go to tab2 the buttons on that page work.  If I then go back to tab1 the buttons work there.  The same also happens in reverse:  if I go to tab2 first and click the buttons they do not work, but if I go to tab1 they do work.  Returning back to tab2, the buttons are now working.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

EDIT:  Below is a cut down version of the code for the page.  The event handlers are currently in the header.  I have already tried putting them at the bottom of the body as well though.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>Profile Page</title>
            <link href="../css/profilepage_s.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <!-- Importing javascript configuration file and library of functions to call Facebook features -->
            <?php include('../../config_js.php'); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/facebookFeatures.js"></script>

             <!-- This is all jQuery code -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    <!-- Converts Link into button -->
                    //$("#thisIsAButton").button();


                    <!-- Updates the user's shortlist with id of this person -->
                    $("#updtShortlistBtn").click(function () {
                        alert("I'm in");

                        //$(this).hide();

                        $.get('../Scripts/updateShortlist.php', 'uid=<?php echo $uid?>&targ_id=<?php echo $targ_id?>');
                    }); 
                });
            </script>​​​

        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="container">

            <a id="thisIsAButton" href="../View/edit_profile.php">go to page 4</a>

            <?php //echo $targ_id ?>

            <!-- Displays the Profile Picture -->
            <div id="profile_pic">
                <img src="<?php echo $picture ?>"/>
            </div>

            <!-- Displays list of comparisons-->
            <div id="comparison"></div>
            <div id="bio"><?php //echo $bio ?></div>

            <!-- Show different views if user is viewing their own profile or another user's profile -->
            <!-- These features should only be available if the user is viewing their own profile -->
            <?php 

                if ($activeUsersProfile){ ?>
                    <!-- Edit Profile Button -->
                    <div id="editProfileBtn">
                        <button data-pagelink="../View/edit_profile.php">Edit Profile</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button to publish a summary of user's app profile to their Facebook profile -->
                    <div id="publishBtn">
                        <input type="button" value="Publish Profile" onclick="publishToWall(<?php echo $targ_id ?>)"/>
                    </div>

            <?php } else { ?>

                            <!-- Displays Send Message Button and Update shortlist button -->
                    <div id="sndBtn">
                            <button type="button" id="updtShortlistBtn">Say 'Hey'!</button>
                    </div>  
<?php } ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

                $(document).on('click', '#updtShortlistBtn', function () {

                alert("I'm in");
                 $.get('../Scripts/updateShortlist.php', 'uid=<?php echo $uid?>&targ_id=<?php echo $targ_id?>');
            });

            });
```

EDIT2:  Sorry, while trying to shorten my example code I took out some buttons which did not have jQuery such as the one below.  I realise now that this might be important to finding the solution!

```
// Calls a method in the facebookFeatures.js file linked at top
<button type="button" id="sndMessageBtn" onclick="sendMessage(<?php echo $targ_id ?>)">Send Message</button>
```

Comment: Where are the event handlers for your buttons being bound? Some relevant code in the question would help

Comment: @BLSully Thanks for the reply - the event handlers are currently located in the header.  They used to be just before the closing body tag but I thought it may be safer to place them up there.  Let me know if you would like me to cut down the code further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are being bound on document ready, so i'm assuming that maybe the buttons don't exist then? You say the tab's are loaded via ajax, so they do not (likely) exist at the time document ready fires.

There is an event in the jQuery tab for `load` where you should put your click-binding

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    load: function() {
        $("#updtShortlistBtn").click(function () { /* do Stuff */ });
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could bind to the document with a delegated handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#updtShortlistBtn', function () {
    //do Stuff
});
```

This way it doesn't matter when the button's exist...the handler is bound to the document and event bubbling takes care of the issue

Comment: I don't see anything offhand that looks wrong... I _do_ notice you aren't loading the script for jQueryUI in your html head. Maybe that's just your 'demo' code though.

Comment: That's only the css file. You need the javascript file too. It's usually called `jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js` (or similar depending on version)

Comment: Also you're missing the `http:` in the jquery include...`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Fixed that stuff, but still not working... I don't get this!  Why would it only start working once another tab has been clicked?!

Comment: @user1058210: Where are the tabs in the html above? Is the example code above one of the 'contents' of the tabs? If so, what does the parent look like? Sorry we haven't found you a solution yet... there's some missing pieces to the puzzle yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help man!  The problem was with my php session.  Up until now I have only had to start the session once, but I have just found out you're supposed to do this at the top of every page.  I did this then and it started working!  The very concerning thing is that it never threw any errors when things were going wrong, and furthermore buttons which didn't even rely on the session variables were failing!  Thanks A LOT for the help - it turns out my code doesn't work without the answer above anyway!